# Problem with proving that set is complete

Tags: banach-spaces, functional-equations

Problem is next:Let $E$ is normed vector space.
If for every sequence $x_n$ that satisfies $\sum_{n=1}^\infty ||x_n|| < \infty$ exists $y \in E$ such that $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n x_k = y$, then $E$ is complete.

We suppose that $x_n$ is Cauchy sequence and then we need to show that this sequence is convergent. I tried using definition of Cauchy sequence, but I can't get so much.

Comment: I believe you mean $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} ||x_n||<\infty$?

Comment: Yes, I made mistake.

Comment: Thanks for helping.